# Авторизация на IP камере Dahua через HTTP API

Tags: linux, http, ip, камера, авторизация

**В документации к камере написано:**

> Video products support either basic authentication or digest authentication, see RFC 2617 for detail. If the http request sent by client does not provide valid "Authorization" header information, video products would return HTTP status code 401 and some information for authentication, then client should calculate authentication information according RFC 2617, and sent request again with authentication information using “Authorization” header. Video products return the required resource only if authorization information correct.
>
> For example, when basic authentication fails, response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="XXXXXX"
```

> The client encodes the username and password with base64, and then
> sends it to server. A valid Authorization like this:

```
Authorization: Basic VXZVXZ
```

> The client calculates the digest authorization using information like
> username, password, nonce, HTTP method and URI with MD5, and then
> sends it to server.

**Я пытаюсь авторизоваться с помощью заголовка, как написано, но получаю `401 Unauthorized`.**

**Вот, что я пытался делать:**

```
curl \
-H "Authorization: Basic $(echo "admin:admin" | base64)" \
-vG http://192.168.1.108:80/cgi-bin/global.cgi?action=getCurrentTime
*   Trying 192.168.1.108:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.1.108 (192.168.1.108) port 80 (#0)
> GET /cgi-bin/global.cgi?action=getCurrentTime HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.1.108:80
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4K
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="Login to XXX",qop="auth",nonce="XXX",opaque="XXX"
< Connection: close
< CONTENT-LENGTH: 0
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

**А также:**

```
ncat -C 192.168.1.108 80
GET /cgi-bin/global.cgi?action=getCurrentTime HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.108:80
Accept: */*
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4K

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="Login to XXX",qop="auth",nonce="XXX",opaque="XXX"
Connection: close
CONTENT-LENGTH: 0
```

**Как видно, ничего не выходит. Подскажите, что я делаю не так? Спасибо**

Comment: Digest попробуй

Comment: @eri, а в этом случае мне не нужно использовать base64? Т.е. это должно выглядеть как-то так: `Digest: MD5=admin:admin`?

Comment: У курла есть параметр авторизации

Comment: @eri, на самом деле, я пишу C++ либу, а сейчас просто экспериментирую)) В веб-технологиях не силен

Comment: У libcurl тоже есть готовая автортзация.

Comment: @eri, все таки curl не может так авторизоваться `curl --user "admin:admin" -vG http://192.168.1.108:80/cgi-bin/global.cgi?action=getCurrentTime`

Comment: curl --digest  -u{username}:{password}...

Comment: @eri, кажется я нашел способ. Достал из Firefox запрос. Попробую так пока

Comment: @eri, спасибо! Только этот способ помог. Причем, первый раз возвращается 401, а дальше 200. Очень странно это работает.

Comment: digest устроен так что работает со второго раза)

Comment: @eri, я уже догадался. Вообще, мне бы понять откуда там берется хэш `respose` и `cnonce`, и, возможно, обойдусь без libcurl. Планировалось использование Boost.Asio.

Comment: из первого запроса, формулы расчета есть на википедиях кмк. В бусте нет digest?

Comment: @eri, в Asio вроде нет. Возможно в Beast есть.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$link_check = "http://".$ip."/cgi-bin/magicBox.cgi?action=reboot";
    
    $ch = curl_init($link_check);
    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $camera_login.":".$camera_password);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
    
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,'Basic '.base64_encode("$camera_login:$camera_password"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT , 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    $response=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Бэйсик авторизация не принимается камерой, возможно надо включить в настройках.

Камера требует Digest автризацию. Она проходит со второго раза. При первой попытке сервер генерирует параметры для сессии. На второй попытке прининимает авторизацию с учётом этих значений.